# Cannot insert data into mysql table via php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure this question has been asked a thousand times but after an hour of truly trying many examples on the web, I have failed to insert new data into my table. I have tried many methods as I said, the one I'm about to post is most recent. If anyone knows why my code is failing it would save so much stress. I have only so far managed to insert data via phpmyadmin. The database is called "test" and the table is called "getting". Please note that "key" is auto incremented.

Thank you

```
$username='****';
$password='****';
$database='test';



    $con= mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);

     mysql_select_db("test",$con);




    mysql_query("INSERT INTO getting (Key, Date, amount, tax, Extra) 
    VALUES ('', 'sept 26 2008', '35653', '46', '454')");
```

Comment: have you tried to escape the key? like: `(\`key\`, ...)`

Comment: You should put between backticks keywords, format date as YYYY-MM-DD to be sure it's correctly taken and show us which error you are getting...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try

1. put keywords between backticks
2. format date as YYYY-MM-DD
3. don't use quotes for numbers
4. use `NULL` for auto-increment keys (you could also remove it from `INSERT`)
5. perform error checking

Try this query

```
$res = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO getting (`Key`, `Date`, amount, tax, Extra) 
    VALUES (NULL, '2008-09-26', 35653, 46, 454)");
if (!$res) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else  {
    // Do here what you need
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks Marco. Will accept. I believe the issue was that I put quotes around amount, tax, and extra? Not sure though.

Comment: @Teddy13: if you perform error checking, an error will be printed on screen if query is wrong telling you which part is wrong, so making it easier to fix it! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO getting (Key, Date, amount, tax, Extra) 
    VALUES ('', 'sept 26 2008', '35653', '46', '454')") or die(mysql_error());
```

What does it say after execution? If there is an error in request - you will see it.

Comment: @Marco          Sorry, I'm here for the second day only )
It is not really a question, it is a hint.

Comment: Don't worry, after you edited adding `or die` part it's OK :)

Answer (score 0):

my guess would have been "4. use NULL for auto-increment keys" by marco too

Answer (score 0):

I belive if the 'key' filed is autoincremented you may not even bother mentioning it in your insert statement.
Something like this

```
INSERT INTO getting (Date, amount, tax, Extra) 
VALUES ('sept 26 2008', '35653', '46', '454')
```